# WCF WSDL has xsd:import statements in one environment, but not the other

Tags: .net, wcf, wsdl

In our INT and QA environments, the WSDL for a simple WCF service looks like this:

```
<wsdl:types>
  <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://blahService/Imports">
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://server:80/blahService/blahService.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://genericHeader"/>
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://server:80/blahService/blahService.svc?xsd=xsd3" namespace="http://blahServiceNamespace"/>
  </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

But in prod, it looks like this:

```
<wsdl:types>
  <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://blahService/Imports" />
</wsdl:types>
```

I have read a lot of posts about flattening the WCF-generated WSDL to include the xsds directly in the WSDL, and even more posts about how to make the schemaLocation point to a specific URL instead of whatever URL the request comes from, but what I want to know is... why is the WSDL different in the two different environments, and how how do we fix it?

Comment: It would require more diagnostics because WSDL should really not be different. It looks like prod is exposing different service. Are there any other differences? Can you create working proxy from the WSDL exposed in the production? Are you exposing SOAP service?

Answer (score 1):

WSDL is generated on the fly by WCF. Check that the mex endpoint is exposed in PROD.

As a caveat, be careful about flattening WSDLs to eliminate imports. Depending on how complex your DTO object graph is, it's possible that the XSDs will be "broken" due to cross-references. In such a case .NET tools work just fine to create proxy classes but we've experienced Java tools and other XML validation tools failing miserably due to malformed schemas.

Comment: The web.configs of the INT/QA/PROD environments are all the same. They all include the following line: `<endpoint name="HttpMexEndpoint" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />`

Comment: Try copying your entire INT/QA service as is to the PROD box and setting it up in IIS as a *new* service on some other port. Does the AppPool set to run as 4.0? Any exceptions if you call the service with proxies generated against "working" WSDL?

Answer (score -1):

```
[XmlSerializerFormat]
    public partial interface IInterface
    {        [OperationContract]
        Response test(test[] tests);
    }
```